# Java String appending a double quote

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to replace all brackets in a String with the double quote character.

I thought this would work:

```
"[foo".replaceAll(Pattern.quote("["), Pattern.quote("""));
```

but it does not.  Can anyone help me understand what I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes

```
"[foo".replaceAll(Pattern.quote("["), "\"");
```

Comment: For some reason, this gives me: Q"Efoo istead of "foo. @JRaymond's approach gives "foo. Does it caused by the second Pattern.quote?

Comment: @dragon66 yes... the second argument is just supposed to be a plain replacement string, not a regular expression

Comment: @JRaymond: +1 for confirming this. I am still wondering why this post seems to work for others but not me judging from the vote-ups.

Comment: @dragon66 Sorry guys, updated the answer. I'm also surprised it got 4 upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

replaceAll takes strings

```
"[foo".replaceAll("\\[", "\""));
```

Might I also add [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) as a good place to test your regex strings

Comment: you missed a backslash escaping

Answer (score 1):

```
"[foo".replaceAll("\\[", "\"")
```

to escape special characters in strings, like " \, you prepend a \, so \" becomes ", \\ becomes \, etc...

Comment: This does not work because [ is a meta-character in regexp patterns. You need to escape it to work. This is why the OP used Pattern.quote

Comment: "[foo".replaceAll("\\[", "\"")..?

Comment: hmm... if I do 2 \ then stackoverflow prints just 1 \, so the post didn't show what I was trying to communicate... lesson learned... :-p

Comment: You need to put 4 spaces in front of your code so that SO detects it is code and then it won't escape it

Answer (score 1):

```
"[foo".replaceAll(Pattern.quote("["), "\"") ;
```

The second argument - replacement - is a common string (doesnt need quotation).

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

"[foo".replaceAll("\[", "\\"")

Notes:

1. replaceAll interprets its first argument as a regular expression.
2. you need to escape (within the regex context) the opening bracket or it will be malformed.

Comment: No it does not work because you must put 2 backlashes in front of the bracket